# Create view of linked tables and avoid NULL values in SQL

Tags: sql, view, null

I have two tables `Table_Company` and `Table_House` which are linked. They contain the columns `C_Index` *(unique)*, `C_Name` and `H_Index` *(unique)*, `C_Index`, `H_Renovated` *(FALSE / TRUE)*, `H_Cost` *(NULL values allowed)*  respectively. The column `C_Index` makes the link between the two tables.

How do I create a view which brings together `C_Name` and `H_Cost` for each company's house which is renovated (`H_Renovated`=*TRUE*) with the lowest cost (lowest value for `H_Cost` which is not *NULL*)? It should show for each company which was the lowest cost to renovate a house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
select c.c_name, h.h_index, h.h_cost
from @table_company c
join @table_house h on c.c_index = h.c_index
join  (select h_index, MIN(h.h_cost) as h_cost
from @table_house h
where h.h_cost is not null 
and h_renovated = 1
group by h_index) as x on x.h_index = h.h_index and x.h_cost = h.h_cost
```

Comment: Tree Frog's answer is good. However, there's a disadvantage in the dataset. If there is, in `table_house`, five times the same combination `[c_index ; h_cost]`, four times with `h_renovated` = 0 and once with `h_renovated` = 1, there will be five times the output `[c_index ; h_cost]` instead of only once. How to avoid that the entries with `h_renovated` = 0 are given as output if they have the same value for `h_cost` as the entry with `h_renovated` = 1?

Comment: It's now answered with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352218/unique-results-for-sql-command-with-group-min-and-null-values).