# Unique results for SQL command with GROUP, MIN and NULL values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, null, unique, min

I have a table `inquiry` with columns `job`, `gender` (`TRUE` for women, `FALSE` for men) and `salary`. None of the columns is unique, `salary` may contain `NULL`. How to find the minimum `salary` per `job` for women (`TRUE`)? If e.g. there are entries `[pilot ; TRUE ; 100]`, `[pilot ; FALSE ; 100]`, `[pilot ; TRUE ; NULL]` and `[pilot ; FALSE ; 120]`, the code below returns `[pilot ; 100]` twice instead of once.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT T.JOB, T.SALARY
FROM INQUIRY AS T INNER JOIN
    (SELECT JOB, MIN(SALARY) AS SL
    FROM INQUIRY AS T
    WHERE (SALARY IS NOT NULL) AND (GENDER = 1)
    GROUP BY JOB) AS x ON x.JOB = T.JOB AND x.SL = T.SALARY
```

Comment: i've change the tag from MySQL to SQL-server.. SQL-server supports the keyword TOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate functions ignore `null`s. Lose the join and you should be OK:

```
SELECT   job, MIN(salary)
FROM     inquiry
WHERE    gender = 1
GROUP BY job
```